# I am trying to set up Leaflet map by their tutorial but something isn't working, can anyone take a look and see why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, leaflet

I am currently trying to follow the step by step instructions on the [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) page on how to set up a basic map but something isn't working for me, the map is not showing up at all. I downloaded the Leaflet-stable release and put all those files in a folder and in it I also created index.html file.

Here is the code I have so far,

```
This is the HTML file

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
    <script src="leaflet.js"></script>

///The above part comes from the download page from Leaflet.com. They say that if you download the files, the code above is what you should put in the head section///

    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="mapid"></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is the .css. file. The instructions say that I have to add this "#mapid { height: 180px; }" in the .css file. Do I simply copy it in like this?

Original .css file that comes with leaflet.

```
/* required styles */

.leaflet-pane,
.leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow,
.leaflet-tile-container,
.leaflet-pane > svg,
.leaflet-pane > canvas,
.leaflet-zoom-box,
.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
```

My .css file with the #mapid { height: 180px; } code

```
/* required styles */

#mapid { height: 180px; }

.leaflet-pane,
.leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow,
.leaflet-tile-container,
.leaflet-pane > svg,
.leaflet-pane > canvas,
.leaflet-zoom-box,
.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below code will help you.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <title>Leaflet, Demo Fazal!</title>
    <style>#mapid { height: 380px; }</style>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div id="mapid"></div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
 integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
 crossorigin=""></script>
    <script>
    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([22.306841, 73.119037], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([22.306841, 73.119037]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is so different from the instructions on their page, I don't think I would have ever managed to get it working myself. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Slebbog, I think the key thing is to ensure the script calling leaflet is _beneath_ the `<div id="mapid"></div>`. You could probably move that in your original code and it would work. Best practice is to place any scripts just above the `</body>` tag rather than in the header.